# How do I print out each iteration of the for loop in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print out each iteration but instead it's printing out the last value as many times as the input. How do I fix it?

Code 1:

```
for i in range (1,n+1):
    
    if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 != 0:
       print("Fizz")

    if n % 5 == 0 and n % 3 != 0:
        print("Buzz")

    if n % 3 == 0 and n % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")
```

If I input 15, for example, it prints out "FizzBuzz" 15 times. I want it to print out something like this:

```
Sample Output:
1, 2, Fizz, 4, ..., Fizzbuzz
```

Comment: please add your codes in proper coding format, not in pictures.

Comment: You sound like someone in need of a debugger.  PyCharm has one built into it.  VSCode probably does too.  I like pudb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need are a couple minor modifications:

```
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    
    if i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 != 0:
        print("Fizz")

    elif i % 5 == 0 and i % 3 != 0:
        print("Buzz")

    elif i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0:
        print("FizzBuzz")

    else:
        print(i)
```

You were making the mathematical tests against `n`, not `i`.